# Django: Annotating difference of two fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class P (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    votes_up = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    votes_down = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
P.objects.annotate(rating = Count(votes_up) - Count(votes_down)).order_by('-rating')
```

?

Comment: have you tried doing what you want to do? :)

Comment: Yes. I got "Unsupported operand type for -: 'Count' and 'Count'".

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
You either write your own aggregate function and then use it in your annotation (which is really a bad idea) or simply rely on raw sql.

Personally, I'd handle that use case with a denormalized counter, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using m2m relations to represent votes? Maybe change that to integerfields instead. Then you could have a model method that returns the subtracted amount. And then maybe you could annotate on the model method instead.